# AppleScript and Numbers: How do I add a row?

Tags: applescript, numbers

This has to be simple: I want to use AppleScript to add a new row at the top of a Numbers sheet called WorkoutSheet in a table called WorkoutDB in a Numbers document call Workout.numbers. (Using Numbers 5.01 on macOS Sierra).

This AppleScript throws the error *"Can’t get sheet "WorkoutSheet"*.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    open "/Users/username/Desktop/Workout.numbers"
    delay 2 --- added, but doesn't help
    tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet"
        add row above first row
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Edit: this works; the key was the use of of `document 1' in the tell block:**

```
tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet" of document 1
```

And the `delay 2` doesn't make a difference; Applescript waits for Numbers to launch and the document to open.

---

I also added the `tell` block

```
tell column "A"
set value of cell 1 to short date string of (current date)
end tell
```

to add the current date to the first colun of the new row.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    open "/Users/markr/Desktop/Workout.numbers"
    tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet" of document 1
        add row above first row
        tell column "A"
            set value of cell 1 to short date string of (current date)
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: You may need a pause to be sure the file has loaded

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work; same error.

Comment: Try changing `tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet"` to `tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet" of document 1` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user3439894  thanks! That was it. Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet"
```

Use:

```
tell table "WorkoutDB" of sheet "WorkoutSheet" of document 1
```

This way Numbers know which document to communicate with.